# Firefox Websocket connection not closing after the tab or browser is closed

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I've tested the connection in google chrome browser, its connecting and disconnecting ok, but why firefox is not closing the connection after it is closed?

I've tried to add this part of code:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    ws.close();
});
```

but it didn't helped, are there any other hacks to solve this?

also I've tried in the server side to put this:

```
byte d = bytes[0]; //first byte
if(d == 0x8)
{
   System.out.println("DISCONNECT");
}
```

but not helped, any other hacks?